# Return value from script

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using script, thad add input lines. `Counter` count value off added lines. I want to return count value, and use it to ButtonClick function to `for` cycle. How I am able to do that?

Script that added lines:

```
 <script>
    var counter = 1;
            $(function () {
                $('#add').click(function () {
                    $('<tr id="tablerow' + counter + '"><td>' +
                        '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="ClientSampleID[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="AdditionalComments[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="removeTr(' + counter + ');"><b>-</b></button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>').appendTo('#submissionTable');
                    counter++;
                    return false;
                });
                return counter;
            });
            function removeTr(index) {
                if (counter > 1) {
                    $('#tablerow' + index).remove();
                    counter--;
                }
                return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Button click function:

```
void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string marker= "Marker";
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
        {
           file.WriteLine("{0}", marker);
        }
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can't directly call javascript function from c# code-behind . You will need to use other techniques to obtain the value, such as AJAX

Comment: set a hidden field to the counter value - that way you can pickup/use that value in your code behind click event.